# Android Spinner control not showing the text?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner

I am using spinner in my android project to choose options.Its working fine but not showing the text after selecting from drop-down.My Spinner code looks like following:

```
            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/timeSpinner"
                android:layout_width="0.0dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                android:background="@drawable/rectangle_shape_middle"
                android:entries="@array/time_arrays"
                android:paddingLeft="6.0dip"
                android:prompt="@string/time_prompt"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="16.0sp" />
```

I have the same problem in my whole project.Earlier it was working fine but now its not showing the selected text.I have make sure the text color is black(#000000) but no success.

Comment: In which API version this problem in occurs? and how it open the spinner prompt either in black or white color.

Comment: @Sri API version 17.I am testing it on my nexus 4.Although it was working yesterday but not now

Comment: can you please add an screenshot.And also add you adapter setting so that i will get to know and review it.

Comment: @Sri this spinner is not using any adpater, just using "@array/time_arrays".

Comment: Everything is fine in your code dude.Even me too don't know what is the problem. Try to check the background and change some other color for text. I will let you know if find anything useful for you.